# Counting distinct monomials in the power of a polynomial?

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, generating-functions

Let $p = \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-2} x_i^3 + x_i x_{i+1} x_{i+2}\right) + x_{n-1}^3 + x_n^3$, as a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots, x_n]/\langle \{ x_i^5 = 0\ \forall\ i\}\rangle$. Let $t \in \mathbb{N}$. How many distinct monomials are in $p^t$?

The background here is combinatorics, where I'm counting the possible distinct results after $t$ moves, where a move is to either pick $x_i^3$, or $x_i x_{i+1} x_{i+2}$, and we can pick a variable at most 4 times. $n$ here is quite large, but $t$ is small.

Full disclosure: This is part of a programming challenge. I'm thus fine with an answer of "Check out [this theorem] about generating functions" or the like. :)

Comment: Thanks for the full disclosure. Are you aware of the [contest problem policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy)?

Comment: I hadn't, but just read it. It seems this doesn't count as a contest because it is not time-limited. The question arose as one attack avenue for a Project Euler problem. Is there something in particular I should do? (Like emailing mods/someone a link to the problem?)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read it. I don't think there's anything else to do if the challenge isn't time-limited. If someone disagrees, they can let the mods know. Note [this meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21383) specifically about Project Euler, where the most upvoted answer quotes the contest problem policy and suggests not to treat Project Euler questions differently from other questions.

Comment: @joriki If this is something the OP arrived at when solving a problem, I don't see any harm in posting it. They don't seem to be posting the problem itself, but a byproduct of their own attempt at cracking it.